# MATLAB How to move a menu to center of screen

Tags: matlab, user-interface, positioning

I'm trying to get a matlab menu to the center of my screen, so normally i'd write it like this;
`choice = menu('choose','1','2');`
`movegui('choice','center')`
But since matlab waits for an input before executing the second line, it doesn't move the gui.
I've seen some workarounds but most of them are really long or ugly.
How do I fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility would be to copy the content of the menu.m file into a new function, rename it and add this line:

```
movegui(menuFig,'center');
```

on line 229. Although I must say that it might be illegal or be against the terms of service...if that's the case I'm not even sure I should propose this. Anyhow by typing `edit menu` in the command window one can see that the function simply creates a figure (whose handles is `menuFig`) and adds the number of pushbuttons with appropriate strings corresponding to the number of inputs you provided the function, so in fact that's not that hard to create your own function based on this idea... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Well i think such programming is allowed in my area, so how'd you add that line to menu.m exactly?

Comment: Since menu.m is a Read-only file, copy/paste the whole file to a new function and place the code above on line 229, right after this code (line 228): set( menuFig, 'Position', [winLeftGap bottom winWide winHigh]); That's just before making the figure visible after all of its components have been created.

Comment: Haha that's a pretty huge workaround then, but to be fair it'll achieve just what i'd like to see, that's true... Thanks man

Comment: True! Since you specified in your question that you saw long/complicated stuff I went with a short and sweet workaround haha. Cheers!